# Do anyone has infinite tapas Shakti (power) other than Brahman?

Tags: brahman, tapasya

It is well known that Brahman has infinite power.

Other than him, in general, sages have tapas power due to their tapas and can be used for their wish such as cursing someone or for own purposes or for dharma. The tapas Shakti then decreases after using it.

Does anyone other than Brahman has never-ending Tapasya power?

Comment: Sages using tapas as per their wish? Where did u get this? If a sage wants rain as per his wish can he bring rain ? Understand when shakti increases responsibility increases. So think before using those words

Comment: Brahman's power is not due to tapasya. It exists by itself forever. For others, it is based on karma, like bank-credit. so.. No. Proof lies in the immortality boon that is always asked and always denied.

Comment: @AkshayS Like gandhari used to curse Krishna...

Comment: @ram Yeah, it may not due to tapasya. My intention is to say that there are no limits for his power.

Comment: @hanugm You used sages and now saying Gandhari. Is Gandhari a women sage? Sages have responsbility and do not use as per their wish. They use it for Dharma. There's nothing personal here. If you use for personal and if that has consequence on cosmic dharma, then you will be put in hell. Agathyar has said in his writings dont get trapped in Maya of tapa shakti.

Comment: With regards to infinite tapa shakti, it would happen, one who has completely destroyed his Ahamkara, and is oness with the Parabrahman. One who is pure in body, mind, does his Dharma properly, completely devoid of "I have attained Brahman, I am Guru" sense, this ahamkara sense should be devoid, compassion, devotion to Ishwar, all these qualities helps find union, oness with Parabrahman where there's no I entity. In this stage, one doesnt lose power of tapa shakti. But this is extremely highest stage where it requires, patience, calmness, devotion etc....

Comment: Power of Rishis come from Brahman. Hence rishis of Vedas said "Aham Brahmasmi - My real "I" is Brahman"."Ayam Aatma Brahman- My soul is Brahman"

Comment: No noone has inf power.

Comment: Yes. Ashwini Kumaras and other ‘Universal up-keep’ deities has infinite powers as per rules of this Universe.

Answer (score 2):

As per **Chapter 5th of Kurma Purana**,

> 17b. One day of god Brahma is called a Kalpa and his
>   night is of the same duration.
>
> 18. -19. Learned men say that a thousand sets of four
>       yugas constitute one Kalpa. Three hundred and sixty Kalpas
>       make one year of god Brahma, O excellent Brahmanas,
>       Hundred times of that period is called a Parardha by them.
> 19. At the close of that period, all living beings get dissolved in Prakrti, their source. Hence, this is called the reabsorption into
>       Prakrti (Prakrta Pratisaicara) by wise men.
> 20. It is said that in due course of time, Brahma, Narayana and Isa (Rudra), all the three, become merged in Prakrti and their
>       remanifestation also is to take place.
> 21. Thus, Brahma, the elements (or all living beings) and even Vasudeva and Sankara are created by Kala. He alone devours them again.
> 22. This Lord Kala is beginningless, endless, free from old age or decay and immortal. He is the Supreme Ruler because of his
>       omnipresence, independence and his state of being the soul of all.
> 23. There have been many Brahmas, Rudras, Narayanas and others, but there is one Lord controller of all viz. Kala. He is omniscient. So
>       states the Śruti (Vedas).

As you can see no one remains forever other than Brahman (in above verses name Kala is used for Brahman) and to show some power one must be alive. So, other than Brahman, no one has never-ending powers.

Comment: It implies that everyone is mortal... But even during the time of his/her life, it does not say information about possessing infinite Tapasya power...

Comment: Suppose Brahman took birth as human Krishna and Krishna has infinite power.

Comment: This answer is partially not right. One who has gone beyond time through power of Yoga, and is eligible to become absorbed in Parabrahman, for him no time affects him. He exists even after Pralayas.... That's why its called immortality crossing over 4 stages of life = birth death oldage disease!!!! Ones who dont have realisation of Atma, merge with Prakriti. the 1st unmanifest. But there's 1 more unmanifest beyond this. 1st one is Akshara Purusha, and second is Adi Purusha.

Answer (score 1):

Sri Krishna said in B.G.:

> मां च योऽव्यभिचारेण भक्ितयोगेन सेवते।
>
> स गुणान्समतीत्यैतान् ब्रह्मभूयाय कल्पते।।14.26।।
>
> Whosoever serves Me alone with an unfailing devotion-Yoga, he, transcending these Strands, turns to be the Brahman.

---

One must understand that the purpose of reaching highest stage in SPIRITUALITY/BRAHMAN, is to attain ABSOLUTE BLISS , but not to attain powers/siddhis .

Attaining powers/siddhis or concentration, etc, may occur as a consequence of doing mantra japa or meditation , etc.

In the case of some persons, this may result only in **ABSOLUTE BLISS** but not in attaining powers.

Sri Krishna in earlier era, Sri Shirdi Sai in our era exhibited Superhuman powers, whereas Sri Ramana Maharshi did not.

It depends on one's prArabdha (stored merit of the body).

Comment: You did not answered the question!

Comment: @Wikash_: I had stated - "Sri Krishna in earlier era, Sri Shirdi Sai in our era exhibited Superhuman powers .....".  Please check.  What more do you want?

Comment: He did not have infinite (shakti) powers.

Comment: @Wikash_: You have to clarify 2 issues here.  1) you had stated He did not have infinite (shakti) powers - please clarify whom are your referring to by "He" (2) Infinite powers -  What do you mean by" Infinite powers"? And, Can you clarify what actions will be treated as done out of those powers?

Comment: Please read the OPs question carefully.

Comment: @Wikash_:The OP in his stated that ".....sages have tapas power due to their tapas and can be used for their wish such as cursing someone or for own purposes or for dharma....".  Do you want clarification to this extent or something else?  Again, you have not clarified as to whom you are referring to: "He did not have infinite (shakti) powers"